# Entity framework and Data broker

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

If I used Entity framework, do I still need to use Data broker design pattern? I used both on my last C# project. But recently someone told me I don't need Data broker while I am using entity framework.

Comment: Without showing any code or argumentation this will lead to a pointless debate. In Sw answers are not always black and white. Depending on the circumstances a good practice in one project is bad in another.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I totally agree. There's no reason to abandon the broker. Of course, have to work with EF at lower level, it's difficult, but possible. Had that "someone" meant this difficulty?

Comment: I totally agree. Thank you so much for your help.